# React-navigation: Deep linking with authorization

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authorization, react-navigation

We were building a mobile app that needs to have different authorization for different type of users with deeplinking. We're using react-native and react-navigation. was wondering what's a good way to achieve this. High level the idea is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ended up using screenWrapper like [this](https://medium.com/life-at-chime/oops-you-arent-meant-to-see-this-screen-react-navigation-deep-linking-authorization-a8b88a8f9716)